A .targets file that would increment build number on each release build
Original Question
I have a Directory.Build.targets file that would increment build number of the project version when building with Release configuration. I.e., the product version is 1.0.0.0, when built in Release config, this target would make it 1.0.0.1, and so on. For some reason I'm getting this error:
MSB4067 The element <WriteLinesToFile> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized.

Code
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Target Name="IncrementBuildNumber" BeforeTargets="GenerateAssemblyInfo" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <VersionFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)version.txt</VersionFile>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(VersionFile)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="VersionLines"/>
        </ReadLinesFromFile>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <VersionString>%(VersionLines[0])</VersionString>
            <MajorVersion>$([System.String]::Split($(VersionString), '.')[0])</MajorVersion>
            <MinorVersion>$([System.String]::Split($(VersionString), '.')[1])</MinorVersion>
            <PatchNumber>$([System.String]::Split($(VersionString), '.')[2])</PatchNumber>
            <BuildNumber>$([System.String]::Split($(VersionString), '.')[3])</BuildNumber>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <NewBuildNumber>$([System.Int32]::Parse($(BuildNumber)) + 1)</NewBuildNumber>
            <NewVersion>$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchNumber).$(NewBuildNumber)</NewVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <WriteLinesToFile File="$(VersionFile)" Overwrite="true">
            $(NewVersion)
        </WriteLinesToFile>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <Version>$(NewVersion)</Version>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>

Updated Question
The original error was solved thanks to the first answer. However, now I'm facing a weird problem where I cannot evaluate the old version + 1 expression. Neither System.Convert, nor System.Int32.Parse don't work in this MSBuild scenario.
The question is: Is this at all the correct and the most painless way of implementing it? If not, what is the easiest way, given that I want it to work in local builds on Windows and in CI also?

%(VersionLines[0]) is not a valid MSBuild expression. An Item can't be indexed. You may want to read the MSBuild documentation before posting more questions.

I think the content of the write operation needs to be passed as a Lines attribute rather than as the body. <WriteLinesToFile File="$(VersionFile)" Overwrite="true" Lines="$(NewVersion)" />
I used this as a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writelinestofile-task?view=vs-2022#example
This is a guess and I haven't tested it!

This answer is correct. The WriteLinesToFile task and MSBuild tasks in general are passed input values via attributes. The name of the attribute is the parameter name.
